# Can't return an Array list from AsyncTask into Main Activity?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-asynctask, return

I can't figure out how to return the objects from an `AsyncTask` which is embedded in an `ArrayList`. Right now if I try to add the `tours.add(tour);` to the list inside the `AsyncTask`, the returned `return tours;` is always null.

How could I brake out from inside the `AsyncTask` and return these objects successfully to my MainActivity??

The class with the ArrayList:

```
public class JsonParser {

    List<Tour> tours = new ArrayList<Tour>();   
    ToursDataSource datasource;
    private String LOGTAG;
    //Context ctx;  
    //public JsonParser(Context context){
    //  ctx = context;
    //}     

    public List<Tour> startJson(Context context) {      

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();     
        client.get("http://edmondvarga.com/android_dev/party_alarm/test_j.php", 
                new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {                
                try {                   
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("users");

                    for (int i=0; i< contacts.length();i++){
                        JSONObject json = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        Tour tour = new Tour();
                        tour.setTitle(json.getString("title"));
                        //String c = json.getString("content");

                        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Tour created with id:" +tour.getTitle());                        
                        tours.add(tour);                        
                    }                   
                } catch (JSONException e) {                 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                       
            }
         });        

        return tours;           
    }


}
```

Part in my MainActivity:

```
public void createData() {  

    JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
    List<Tour> tours = jp.startJson(this);

    //ToursPullParser parser = new ToursPullParser();
    //List<Tour> tours = parser.parseXML(this);

    for (Tour tour : tours) {
            datasource.create(tour);
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your problem is that the task is asynchronous. The system does the following (image we're just working on a single core for better understanding): `call startJson` `create AsyncTask`, but now the system still runs in `startJson`. Now the system things okay it's the right time to start the async task and it fills your list. But you have returned it already. So the solution is quite simple. At the end of `onSuccess` call an other method, which handles the result for further operations. (Or just do it in `onSuccess`, because this is already on the main thread)

**@Edit:**

```
public class JsonParser {

    List<Tour> tours = new ArrayList<Tour>();   
    ToursDataSource datasource;
    private String LOGTAG;
    //Context ctx;  
    //public JsonParser(Context context){
    //  ctx = context;
    //}   
    private final MainActivity mCallback;

    public JsonParser(MainActivity callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
    }    

    public List<Tour> startJson(Context context) {     

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();     
        client.get("http://edmondvarga.com/android_dev/party_alarm/test_j.php", 
                new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {                
                try {                   
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("users");

                    for (int i=0; i< contacts.length();i++){
                        JSONObject json = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        Tour tour = new Tour();
                        tour.setTitle(json.getString("title"));
                        //String c = json.getString("content");

                        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Tour created with id:" +tour.getTitle());                        
                        tours.add(tour);                        
                    }                   
                } catch (JSONException e) {                 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
                callback.setResult(tours);     
            }
         }); 




public class MainActivity....

    public void createData() {
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(this);
        List<Tour> tours = jp.startJson(this);
    }

    public void setResult(List<Tour> tours) {
        for(Tour t : tours) {
            //....
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have already placed the value ("tours.add(tour);")which I want to return inside onSuccess (); But it has no effect on the return statemen because it is locked inside onSuccess. Even if I start another method from inside onSuccess it will not be called from the MainActivuty and I will not be able to return anything

Comment: Thanks for your negative rating. However, you're calling create Data. This starts the task, but you don't know, when it is finsihed. You could give your JsonParser a reference to `this` from your `MainActivity` and call a method, if it's finished. If this doesn't solve your problem, are you sure, that you've the correct data in tours? I edit my post to visualize my solution.

Comment: thanks, I did not downvote your answer...anyway it is a nice solution for my prob. Thanks!

Comment: Okay than wasn't this message for you. Who did this downvote? Please explain, so I can improve my answers!

Answer (score -1):

In the MainActivity, you need to wait until the AsyncCall is finished. When you call client.get you spawn a separate thread to do the network call and then return the empty list.  Then in MainActivity you get the empty list.  In the onSuccess once you are done parsing you can send a message back to the main activity through a handler or a local broadcast to notify it that the list is updated.